# Как работает поиск сервера в многопользовательских онлайн играх?

Tags: сеть, сокет, разработка-игр, сокеты, сетевое-программирование

Допустим игрок нажимает кнопку `"start"` и через некоторое время заходит на сервер какой-нибудь игры. Меня интересует момент поиска сервера, как он происходит в такой ситуации? Сначала игрок обращается к `"серверу-распределителю"`, который производит соединение данного пользователя с одним из серверов игры? Или это происходит каким-то другим способом?

Comment: Во всех играх по разному. У нас вот централизованная система - есть мастер-сервер, которому все сервера рапортуют о своей работе (раз в пару минут, к примеру). Когда игрок входит в игру, он получает от мастер-сервера список активных серверов и дальше коннектится к любому из них. Уточните вопрос. Что и для чего вам нужно?

Comment: @Kromster просто из-за блокировок РКН часть серверов некоторых игр недоступны, поэтому появилась идея написать программу, которая не будет дожидаться завершения рукопожатия с сервером, если сервер не отвечает за определенное время (меньшее, чем предоставляет сама игра). Да и если это невозможно, то просто интересно, как функционируют игры, у которых насчитывается сотни тысяч серверов.